# Blender: Thick extrude along edges

Tags: blender

I am trying to inset the roof on the top of this building...the roof is below the top of the walls.  As you can see from the picture, there is a thick border along the edge.  What I need is a kind of "create inner edge (or cut) along the border" at the same distance from the existing border all the way around.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

[image: Building]

Answer (score 1):

The [inset tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) will add a border around the selected faces and works well with irregular shapes.

[image: inset in progress]